# Grand Total of TIME DIFFERENCE

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I want to get the grand total of overtime after `endtime` and `starttime` being SUBTRACTED and SUMMED UP by `group`.

Here's my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT o.*, u.* ,p.* ,
            SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dateto, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i%s')) - TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(datefrom, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i%s')))) AS totalHrs,

            SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(totalHrs))) AS grandTotal // Can't make this run
            FROM overtime AS o, users AS u, position AS p
            WHERE o.user_id=u.user_id and u.p_id=p.p_id
            GROUP BY p.p_id
            ORDER BY p.position_name ASC";
```

Here's my database:

```
|-----------|-------------|-------------|-----------------------|---------------------|
|-- ot_id --|-- user_id --|--- p_id ----|------ datefrom -------|------- dateto ------|
|-----------|-------------|-------------|-----------------------|---------------------|
|    1      |      3      |      17     |    12/17/15 17:00:00  |   12/17/15 19:00:00 |
|-----------|-------------|-------------|-----------------------|---------------------|
|    2      |      3      |      17     |    12/17/15 17:00:00  |   12/17/15 19:00:00 |
|-----------|-------------|-------------|-----------------------|---------------------|
|    3      |      10     |      27     |   12/17/15 17:00:00   |   12/17/15 19:00:00 |
|-----------|-------------|-------------|-----------------------|---------------------|
|    4      |      45     |      27     |    12/17/15 17:00:00  |   12/17/15 19:00:00 |
|-----------|-------------|-------------|-----------------------|---------------------|
|    5      |      44     |      5      |   12/17/15 17:00:00   |   12/17/15 19:00:00 |
|-----------|-------------|-------------|-----------------------|---------------------|
```

This is the output:

```
p_id #17 ----> Junior Programmer
     #27 ----> SAP Programmer
     #5 -----> Technician

|----------------------|--------------|
|------ position ------|-- Total Hrs--|
|----------------------|--------------|
|   Junior Programmer  |    4:00:00   |
|----------------------|--------------|
|    SAP Programmer    |    4:00:00   |
|----------------------|--------------|
|      Technician      |    2:00:00   |
|----------------------|--------------|
|       GRAND TOTAL    |   10:00:00   | <-------- CAN'T GET THIS
|----------------------|--------------|
```

Any help could do.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [**WITH ROLLUP**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) function to get cumulative sum of any column.

Try this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(p.position_name, 'Grand Total') AS `position`
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(dateto, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i')) - TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(datefrom, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i')))) AS totalHrs
FROM overtime AS o, users AS u, POSITION AS p
WHERE o.user_id=u.user_id AND u.p_id=p.p_id
GROUP BY p.p_id WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY p.position_name ASC;
```

**OR**

You can also use [**TIMESTAMPDIFF()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function to generate difference to two dates.

```
SELECT IFNULL(p.position, 'Grand Total') AS `position`
        SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,STR_TO_DATE(datefrom, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i'),STR_TO_DATE(dateto, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i')))) AS totalHrs
FROM overtime AS o, users AS u, POSITION AS p
WHERE o.user_id=u.user_id AND u.p_id=p.p_id
GROUP BY p.p_id WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY p.position_name ASC
```

**OR**

```
SELECT o.*, u.* ,p.* ,
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(dateto, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i')) - TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(datefrom, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i')))) AS totalHrs
FROM overtime AS o, users AS u, POSITION AS p
WHERE o.user_id=u.user_id AND u.p_id=p.p_id
GROUP BY p.p_id WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY p.position_name ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't know what's happening but I can't get it working. Also, I found out that when `dateto = 09:30:00 and datefrom = 08:00:00` the subtotal will be `0` instead of `01:30:00`

Comment: @LekzFlores Can you post some sample data to understand what is the problem and allow us to resolve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Oh! My flaws, I've found faults in my code.

The `%H:%i:%s` is necessary in getting the difference and sum of time.

Also I forgot to include `:` in `%H:%i%s`.

Adding this line will get the Grand Total:

```
(select SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dateto, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) - TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(datefrom, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')))) FROM overtime WHERE approve_by=0) AS grandTotal
```

Final Code will be:

```
SELECT o.*, u.* ,p.* ,
            SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dateto, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) - TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(datefrom, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')))) AS totalHrs,

            (select SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dateto, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) - TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(datefrom, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')))) FROM overtime) AS grandTotal

            FROM overtime AS o, users AS u, position AS p
            WHERE o.user_id=u.user_id and u.p_id=p.p_id and o.approve_by=0
            GROUP BY p.p_id
            ORDER BY p.position_name ASC
```